# Add items to a menu

Tags: menus

I'm reading [The Absolute Beginners Guide to Wordpress](http://www.quepublishing.com/store/wordpress-absolute-beginners-guide-9780789752901), but possibly it's too advanced for my purposes.  I cannot get information about basic navigation, wiring the menu to pages.

I've created three menus, `menu_main`, `menu_footer`, `menu_social`.  How do I wire pages to a menu?  When I select a menu to edit and try to "Add Items to A Menu" there are no pages to add.  Wordpress says "No Items."

However, there are a number of pages available from the "pages" link in wordpress.

Why aren't these pages available to be added?  How do I add a page to a menu?

I'm only trying to create static content, very basic site with a menu and four or five pages.

See also:

- [Wordpress Menu User Guide](http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Menu_User_Guide)
- [Add pages in navigation bar](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-add-pages-in-navigation-bar-in-magazine-basic-theme?replies=9)

Comment: Try the WordPress.org forums or your theme forums for these questions as this site is for Development of WordPress and not WordPress support.

Comment: Check [this post](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/160599/31545)