# wp_nav_menu() doesn't work

Tags: menus, navigation

I'm working on a theme with custom menus, currently using WP 4.0.1.

I'm registering two menus in functions.php:

```
register_nav_menus(
    array(
      'primary'   => __( 'Main Menu', 'wsy' ),
      'secondary' => __( 'Secondary Menu', 'wsy' )
    )
);
```

Then, displaying them in my header.php file:

```
<nav role="navigation">
    <?php
        wp_nav_menu(
            array(
                'theme_location' => 'primary',
                'depth'          => '1'
            )
        );
    ?>
</nav>
```

The problem is, when I select a specific menu from either the Menus page or the customizer, they stop showing up in my page. It doesn't matter which menu or which location, they just don't show up. When I reset the locations (choose "- Select -" from the dropdown) a default menu is shown.

WP_DEBUG is active, no errors. Tried it with WP 4.1, still nothing. Tried adding new menus, no luck. Tried with a single menu location and registering with `register_nav_menu();` instead -- nothing works.

I even tried on a fresh WP install, no luck. Also tried without the depth parameter, nothing.

I'd appreciate any help with this. Thanks!

Comment: See [this post](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/160599/31545) on how to create a custom menu. Hope that helps :-)

Comment: @PieterGoosen My code is written like that, but it's still not working. Thank you anyway Pieter :)

Comment: Test this on a freash install without plugins on one of the bundled themes like twentyfifteen. I suspect something in your theme is causing this issue. It is definitely not your code or the code in my linked answer.

Comment: @PieterGoosen Yep, tried that already. Even on the current install, the default themes work without problems. I did a fresh install, my theme doesn't work, while the others do... I'll start commenting different sections of the my code and do trial and error.

Comment: Your problem is not the code you have posted. Are you using any custom filter on `WP_Query` or the main query, or any function hooked to `pre_get_posts` or any instance of `query_posts`.

Comment: @PieterGoosen You're right Pieter. I had a filter set on wp_nav_menu_items that was pulling in some extra items. I forgot I had commented the function responsible for returning those items... Wow, thank you so much for your help. I would have struggled a lot without your idea.

Comment: @PieterGoosen How do I give you a + for reputation?

Comment: Glad I could be of help. Your comment is enough for me :-). Enjoy

Answer (score 0):

You might need to use 'add_theme_support' for 'nav-menus' as well. See line 2 below:

```
if ( function_exists('wp_nav_menu') ) {
  add_theme_support( 'nav-menus' );
  register_nav_menus( array( 
      'primary' => __( 'Main Menu', 'wsy' ), 
      'secondary' => __( 'Secondary Menu', 'wsy' )
      ) 
  );
}
```

Then display your menu like so:

```
$nav_menu = 'primary';
if ( has_nav_menu( $nav_menu ) ) {
echo '<nav role="navigation">';
  wp_nav_menu(
    array(
        'theme_location' => $nav_menu,
        'depth' => 1
    )
  );
echo '</nav>';
}
```

Comment: Still nothing :( The condition is met, the nav tags are  echoed, but wp_nav_menu() still doesn't output anything :(